# Grafana Authentication and Organizations

Tags: grafana

Up until recently, we were using grafana for server level stats, so there was not a compelling requirement to secure access to datasources / dashboards.

Now we have some more business focused datasources / dashboards, which may have sensitive information. For these, we will need to introduce authentication + organizations.

Is there a way to have a 'default' organization in grafana for server metrics, for which a user does not need to authenticate?

Or will we have to resort to having 2 grafana instances: one with authentication enabled for business KPIs, and one without for server metrics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `auth.anonymous` under the [grafana configuration](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/) as this permits anon users to see a specific org without authorisation (or edit depending on the role you assign) but still requires auth for other orgs as you see fit.

For example, the following shows Anon access allowed for 'viewing' dashboard data,

```
[auth.anonymous]
enabled = true
org_role = Viewer
org_name = Company Server Stats
```

You'd then create another organisation for Grafana to use. Note that both orgs will share the same authentication system (I believe...) but data sources will be organisation specific - ensuring that sensitive data remains within the organisation.